# iOS got rejected 5 times

Tags: ios, crash, report, store

I'm a little bit out of ideas right now. 
I have submitted an iPhone app to the AppStore 5 or 6 times till this day and it was always rejected except of one time. I'm still wondering why it was once accepted cause I hardly changed something from the previous version (which was rejected).

BTW: I tested the app on different iPhone 5 and it never crashed...

Anyway, I have problems understanding the crash reports:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x320483e2 0x31f86000 + 795618
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39d4395e ParkingDeckDetailViewController.m:137
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32048302 0x31f86000 + 795394
3   QuartzCore                      0x33c05106 StartupViewController.m:906
4   QuartzCore                      0x33c0502e StartupViewController.m:904
5   UIKit                           0x33ebb944 0x33e54000 + 424260
6   Passau                          0x00196c88 -[AGSGPS setupFrameAndBounds:] (AGSGPS.m:678)
7   Passau                          0x00198056 -[AGSGPS consumeNewLocation:] (AGSGPS.m:928)
8   Passau                          0x00198ffa -[AGSGPS didApproximateProjectionWithGeometry:] (AGSGPS.m:1085)
9   Passau                          0x00197f16 -[AGSGPS locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:] (AGSGPS.m:920)
10  CoreLocation                    0x324f00d6 CityTourDetailViewController.m:234
11  CoreLocation                    0x324e7f38 TabBarViewController.m:90
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3201d920 0x31f86000 + 620832
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3201cff4 0x31f86000 + 618484
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3201c24e 0x31f86000 + 614990
15  CoreFoundation                  0x31f8f238 MapLayerCell.m:50
16  CoreFoundation                  0x31f8f0c4 JSONDataDownload.m:138
17  GraphicsServices                0x35b6e336 MapViewController.m:265
18  UIKit                           0x33eab2b4 0x33e54000 + 357044
19  Passau                          0x000e73aa main (main.m:16)
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a170b1c StartupViewController.m:779
```

and the thread which crashed:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a237350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a1adfb2 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a1ea366 abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39792dda abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39790094 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39d43a58 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39790118 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x397901b0 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39791626 __cxa_rethrow + 90
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39d439b0 objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x31f8f29c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x31f8f0c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  GraphicsServices                0x35b6e336 GSEventRunModal + 70
13  UIKit                           0x33eab2b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  Passau                          0x000fc3aa main (main.m:16)
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a170b1c start + 0
```

I'm using the ArcGIS framework for displaying maps.

So, could you give me a hint where I should lock for an error?
When I read the crashed thread report it seems to me the app crashed right after the start, is that right?

Thanks!

edit: Replaced the "Last Exception Backtrace" with mostly symbolicated version.

+

```
Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x2007a300.events
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a226e98 semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a161c16 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 118
2   CoreLocation                    0x324e7ea4 CLClientInvokeCallback(__CLClient*, CLClientEvent, objc_object*) + 340
3   CoreLocation                    0x324eb4e2 ___CLClientCreateConnection_block_invoke_0 + 346
4   CoreLocation                    0x32521f20 __setEventHandler_block_invoke_0 + 344
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x3a27c882 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 718
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a163688 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke + 120
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a160afa _dispatch_queue_drain + 78
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a16392e _dispatch_mach_invoke + 166
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a160afa _dispatch_queue_drain + 78
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a15e678 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 40
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a160afa _dispatch_queue_drain + 78
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a15e678 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 40
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a161610 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 208
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a1617d4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 88
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a1857ee _pthread_wqthread + 358
16  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a185680 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: No code, no symbolicated crash log, no context, -1.

Comment: So did it indicate the thread that threw the exception?

Comment: @H2CO3 The symbolication doesn't work in xcode (the backtrace & the thread 0 queue are copied from xcode device logs). I tried it with atos but also no success.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I think that Thread 0 crashed. "Crashed Thread:  0"

Comment: Right, I read that. Thread 0 is re-throwing an exception that was originally thrown at the point specified by the "Last Exception Stacktrace". This may indicate that the exception wasn't originally thrown on thread 0. Hence why I asked if there was any indication of which thread originally threw the exception. In particular, are any of your CLLocationManagers interacted with from other threads than the main thread? That would provide a clue.

Comment: Did you added an exception breakpoint?

Comment: @CarlVeazey So, I edited my question and added a symbolicated version of the "Last Exception Stacktrace" and the report from Thread 3 where some CoreLocation stuff is going on.

Comment: @NSPunk No, I did not. Why do you ask?

Comment: We need to see 10 lines of code around ParkingDeckDetailViewController.m line 137, where the crash originated from... from the trace something is bad with the bounds, it's probable you are passing in a bad frame value (like you tried to ask for .frame from a UIView variable that was nil and are using that frame in calculations).

Comment: @Fauphi Great. You're most likely crashing because in general you should never call a UIKit method from anywhere but the main thread. You should probably share the code for your CLLocationManagerDelegate's implementation of didUpdate... Along with any constraints about expensive calculations that need to kept on a background thread. Also would be helpful to see all of the AGSGPS methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Last Exception Stacktrace" is from thread 3, which is not the main thread. However, it was thrown inside a `UIViewController`'s method. This means you are manipulating your interface from another thread besides the main one, which is incorrect and will cause lots of problems of varying severity.

So you need to ensure messages are only sent to view controllers on the main thread. Since `CLLocationManagerDelegate` callbacks happen on the thread from which the manager was started, you should do one of the following:

- Start your `CLLocationManager`s on the main thread only.
- In your code which handles updates in location, either within `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` or somewhere further down the stack, you should do a dispatch_async to the main queue passing a block that does all your messaging to view controllers.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and hope it works. The thing is, the location updates are done by the ArcGIS framework (with [self.parkingDeckMapView.gps start];). But I will try to wrap that in dispatch_async and hope that will do the trick! Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, you're right... looking at that more symbolicated stack trace I am even more confused... what is that MapViewController doing and why is it getting called on thread 3?

Comment: The MapViewController displays a map with various layers of POIs, shows the GPS position on the map, and so on. All done with the ArcGIS framework. I can assure you that I never (in the whole app) change manually to an other thread.

Comment: @Fauphi No NSOperation, dispatch_async, at all? I really am suspicious of your crash reports actually. I'm not sure they symbolicated right...

Comment: No, there is only one dispatch_async:
// this makes sure the change notification happens on the MAIN THREAD
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:self];
    });
I just tried to re-symbolicate the crash report with xcode (installed Command Line Tools), but it still won't do it. Tried again with atos and it shows me the lines which I added to my question. My problem is that I can't recreate the crash and now I have to solve this with the crash report...